# phpmailer 6.0 success message but no mail received using gmail as relay

Tags: email, gmail, phpmailer

I've tried a bunch of alterations to my code but with no effect. The code itself does not return any errors but instead gives a success message. I am using gmail as my relay.

P.S, I commented out `$mail->IsSMTP();` because I saw a similar question here that used it as a fix, I was getting an "smtp failed to connect" error.

I am using PHPmailer 6.0.

Here is my code:

```html
<?php

  require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

  define('GUSER', 'example@gmail.com'); // GMail username
  define('GPWD', '*********'); // GMail password

  function smtpmailer($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body) {
 global $error;
 $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer(true);  // create a new object
 //$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
 $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
 $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
 $mail->Port = 465;
 $mail->Username = GUSER;
 $mail->Password = GPWD;
 $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
 $mail->Subject = $subject;
 $mail->Body = $body;
 $mail->AddAddress($to);
 if(!$mail->Send()) {
  $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
  return false;
 } else {
  $error = 'Message sent!';
  return true;
 }
  }

  smtpmailer('to@mail.com', 'from@mail.com', 'yourName', 'test mail message', 'Hello World!');
  if (smtpmailer('to@mail.com', 'from@mail.com', 'yourName', 'test mail message', 'Hello World!')) {
 // do something
  }
  if (!empty($error)) echo $error;  

 ?>
```

If I uncomment `$mail->IsSMTP();` I get this error log:

> 2017-12-27 07:58:54 Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:465, timeout=300, options=array()
>   2017-12-27 07:58:54 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to smtp.gmail.com:465 (Network is unreachable) [/srv/disk2/2564570/www/consorttest.dx.am/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php line 325]
>   2017-12-27 07:58:54 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Network is unreachable (101)
>   SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Fatal error: Uncaught PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting in /srv/disk2/2564570/www/consorttest.dx.am/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php:1726 Stack trace: #0 /srv/disk2/2564570/www/consorttest.dx.am/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php(1481): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->smtpSend('Date: Wed, 27 D...', 'Hello World!\r\n') #1 /srv/disk2/2564570/www/consorttest.dx.am/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php(1320): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->postSend() #2 /srv/disk2/2564570/www/consorttest.dx.am/mailtest.php(23): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->send() #3 /srv/disk2/2564570/www/consorttest.dx.am/mailtest.php(32): smtpmailer('to@mail.com', 'from@mail.com', 'yourName', 'test mail messa...', 'Hello World!') #4 {main} thrown in /srv/disk2/2564570/www/consorttest.dx.am/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php on line 1726

Answer (score 0):

You're not "using gmail as your relay" if you comment out `isSMTP()` because then it's not using SMTP at all, and will ignore all your SMTP settings. You're sending via your local mail server using PHP's built-in `mail` function.

When sending through gmail, you can't use arbitrary from addresses, though you can preset aliases in your gmail account.

You've based your code on a very old and obsolete example - use the gmail one provided with PHPMailer.

The most important part of the error output is: `Network is unreachable` - that probably means your ISP blocks outbound SMTP - are you by any chance using GoDaddy?

Next up, you have a basic misconfiguration: you're connecting to port 465 using `SMTPSecure = 'tls'`, which means it will try to use SMTP+STARTTLS explicit TLS encryption, and that just won't work on port 465. This is a key reason to use the provided examples - they don't make basic errors like this.

Every one of these things is covered in [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) the error links to.